# Calling an MVC controller from an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm uploading a file and I have validation logic in an MVC controller for the file. This attachment process can be used in the entire application; therefore, I need a directive.

I want to be able (once I click on the Upload button) to call an MVC controller from an Angular directive to eventually send the file to a web service.

Can someone please tell me how I can accomplish this?

I want to be able to use something like the below code inside my directive:

```
$http.post(ajaxUrl)
.success(function (status) {
    if (status.Succeed) {
        alert('file uploaded'
    }
    else {
        alert(status.ErrorResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your MVC server-side call into an Angular service. Inject this service into your directive.

Comment: Jasen, being new to Angular, can you please give me some kind of code example for this?

Comment: Consider wrapping something more advanced like [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) in a custom directive, that points uploads to your service. This allows for richer experiences with upload progress bars and drag/drop uploading.

Comment: Andreas, I already have an html file with an input file to browse with and an Upload button. That's all I need....

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider to create and inject service to your directive?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('service', service);

    function service($http) {
        var url = 'url';

        var service = {
            add: add
        };

        return service;

        function add(data, callback, errorCallback) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });
        };
    }
})();
```

Call of the service in directive

```
service.add(data, function (status) {
});
```